# Controlling for the influence of a third variable in a three-arm, prospective RCT

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-estimating-equations, predictor, controlling-for-a-variable

Thanks in advance for reading and chiming in, if you have any advice.

I'm working on a project that involves testing an intervention that could increase HIV testing rates. Participants will be randomly assigned to three conditions (1: Control, 2: A little intervention, 3: A lot of intervention), and then we'll track whether or not they got an HIV test every three months for a year.

The issue is that we think receiving this intervention may also lead people to seek another clinical service (called pre-exposure prophylaxis) that requires people to be tested for HIV every three months as a part of receiving this service. So, some in the experimental condition (and in others, as well) may get tested merely because they decided to go on PrEP, and not because of the intervention itself. In the most optimistic scenario, though, it's likely that somewhere around 20-30% may fall in this category in this group, but the point is that it may be higher in the experimental conditions compared to control.

Obviously it's a bit more complicated than this, but we'd planned to use logistic regression with condition assignment as a predictor to test whether the odds of testing across the entire study period were different across the groups, and GEE for repeated binary outcomes to test whether the odds of testing within each 3 month window during the study period were different across groups.

**The question is how to address the fact that some participants started receiving this other service (PrEP) during the study period.** Again, while the number of participants who get HIV tests through PrEP care may be higher in the experimental groups, some participants in all groups are likely to have gotten tested for this reason, as well. **Is it sufficient to add PrEP receipt as a covariate in these models, so we can effectively see the odds of testing in those who didn't start PrEP (i.e., those who are at PrEP=0)? Or is there another way of addressing this you might recommend?**

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of evaluating the practical impact of implementing your intervention in the population the fact that it leads to more people using PrEP does not matter. You can see using PrEP if you like as part of the intervention just as any other changes in their behaviour like using more condoms or not sharing needles so much would be. If you are interested in the mechanism by which your intervention has its effect then it does matter and you would include an interaction between your intervention and PrEP (as well as the main effects of course) to see whether the effect was similar.